Software-controlled power limit in Windows 10
I have a Eluktronics Mech G3 laptop that draws a significant amount of power (~180w), enough that it trips circuit breakers in airplanes. It also is too much power for those portable inverters that plug into a car's cigarette lighter. Is there a way to cap max power consumption of a Windows 10 machine to allow use in these situations (to something like 90w, for example)?

Windows 10 (as well as other versions) has setting to limit the CPU's maximum state in Power Options, Change advance power settings:

You can try to set both On battery and Plugged in (i.e., when using airplane or car power, as well as AC mains) to lower values, perhaps 40%.
Though this likely would prevent surges in power draw during use, it would not affect current draw for battery charging. It is possible that with battery at less than 100%, the laptop might still draw too much power for the auxiliary source.
Try testing, after changing CPU power settings, with an inexpensive AC power meter, such as one of these examples. Check power draw under maximum load (e.g., with a tool such as HeavyLoad). Test both with a fully charged battery, and with one about 50% charged, to see if power draw is excessive despite controlled CPU state. You might find you can use that laptop on a plane if you've started with a full charge, but not if the battery is depleted.
